# Can programs see your windows account name given admin rights?

Tags: windows, windows-10

The windows account name can be seen as one the folders in C:\Users. Assuming you changed your windows account name to something different to the folder, can programs see your new windows account name given admin rights?

Comment: Why is this something you want to hide?

Comment: @multithr3at3d probably because OP uses his/her real name as account name and thus fears that anybody getting into that PC can then link to his/her real identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programs can get the current username using [`GetUserName()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getusernamea) and the path of profile directory e.g. using [`GetUserProfileDirectoryA()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-getuserprofiledirectorya). They use API calls instead of deducing something from directory names. And no administrative rights required for these.

Comment: I'm sure the registry would contain this information as well.

Comment: My main point here was that there's no need for using such methods as checking filesystem (or registry), because this is not a secret information and there are standard ways to get it.